# Grub2 Cutomization error

Tags: boot, grub2, 18.10, customization

Over eager noob here.
I've been playing around with updating GRUB on my new install of Ubuntu 18.10.
I was using GRUB Customizer to do most of the edits but it was failing to update my background Image.

I read some documentation about only editing the `/etc/default/grub` file.
I'm currently getting the following error when I try to open GRUB customizer or run `update-grub`:

```
$ sudo update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
/etc/grub.d/40_custom_proxy: 16: /etc/grub.d/40_custom_proxy: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I've looked around and can't find someone having a similar issue and being that I'm the new guy here, I'm not sure where to look to next besides asking for help. Any points in the right direction, tips, or tricks would be greatly appreciated for diagnosing these kinds of errors.

Here's my default grub file for reference:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="-1"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE="1280x720"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"
export GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="brown/black"
export GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT="light-blue/black"
export GRUB_MENU_PICTURE="/home/nicholas/Pictures/Winbuntu_Grub.png"
GRUB_FONT="/boot/grub/unicode.pf2"
```

Let me know if you need me to add any additional information. (All of this and my background is still purple with a question mark boarder, that's an issue for later).

EDIT for more information, updated output of running update-grub.

Export of 40_custom_proxy:

```
#!/bin/sh
#THIS IS A GRUB PROXY SCRIPT
sh -c 'echo "### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/custom ###";
"/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/custom";
echo "### END /etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/custom ###";
echo "### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/linux ###";
"/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/linux";
echo "### END /etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/linux ###";
echo "### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/uefi-firmware ###";
"/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/uefi-firmware";
echo "### END /etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/uefi-firmware ###";' | /etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy "-*
-'"{'
-#text
+'Ubuntu'~f65365815d6524671b174d3a3d8b7446~
+'Windows'~4e5144083f338b3f4c81d7083be85d55~
+'SUBMENU' as 'Advanced Options'{+'Memtest'~5a8aaef18d8fdedc01dc802f3e3a375c~, +'SUBMENU' as 'Advanced options for Ubuntu'{+'Advanced options for Ubuntu'/* from '/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/linux', +'Advanced options for Ubuntu'/'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.18.0-16-generic'~785a2bbd696f9fde2acf13125f556608~ from '/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/linux', +'Advanced options for Ubuntu'/'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.18.0-16-generic (recovery mode)'~b715e6520b269cb0b2eeb36de183f057~ from '/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/linux', +'Advanced options for Ubuntu'/'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.18.0-10-generic'~16a33ff9746d2f2788f6363e721c30e9~ from '/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/linux', +'Advanced options for Ubuntu'/'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.18.0-10-generic (recovery mode)'~b2995c4cff62656f6ce79c4ddf33da8e~ from '/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/linux'}, +'System setup'~4e15a6547b9250de59821b594ecf5dee~ from '/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/uefi-firmware'}
" multi
```

Comment: The error shows that it was file `/etc/grub.d/40_custom_proxy`. Probably `16` represents line number. Please Look into this!

Comment: @PRATAP that is correct, that was my original intention. after applying the background in GRUB Customizer and rebooting my computer, GRUB is still purple, but there is a border of question marks around the screen.

Comment: @Marmayogi I checked into that file and was unable to locate anything relevant. I'll post the output of this file separately.

Comment: @PRATAP i can't even access grub customizer if i watned to. That error is preventing me from opening it.

Comment: $ ls /etc/grub.d/
00_header     
05_debian_theme
10_linux_proxy
40_custom_proxy
43_linux_xen
44_memtest86+
45_os-prober_proxy
46_custom_proxy
47_custom
backup
bin
LS_custom
LS_linux
LS_os-prober
LS_uefi-firmware
proxifiedScripts
README

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was not able to find a conclusive answer. I've reinstalled GRUB form a live session and calling it quits. Thanks for taking a look into it.

Comment: I've never used grub customizer but grub itself looks really great when customized  with backgrounds, colors, graphics, animation, fonts and all that jazz. If you post a question on how to customize grub (without grub customizer) I'd be happy to answer as I'm sure many others will be.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have played a lot with grub/ grub customizer.
If you have not played with 40_custom file, and able to update your grub without errors, then follow below.

**1. To use the custom background for grub..**

open the file `/etc/default/grub` with below command in terminal
`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`

under the lines

```
# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

paste the below content

```
GRUB_BACKGROUND="/home/nicholas/Pictures/Winbuntu_Grub.png"
```

save the file & close. then run `sudo update-grub` and look for the text that starts with "Found background image:" if this text appears, background will work.

Example:

```
$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background: /home/pratap/Pictures/Winbuntu_Grub.png
Found background image: /home/pratap/Pictures/Winbuntu_Grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-34-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-34-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
$
```

**2. to change the grub menu colors..**

open the file `/etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme` with below command in terminal
`sudo -H gedit /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme`

go to line number around 129 and edit the content look like this

```
if [ -z "${2}" ] && [ -z "${3}" ]; then
        # echo "  true"
        echo "set colro_highlight=light-blue/black"
        echo "set color_normal=green/black"
fi
```

save the file & close. then run `sudo update-grub`

reboot to see the changes.

[image]

Reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Displays

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information, unfortunately this hasn't worked. Did as you instructed, rebooted and still have the purple background, border of question marks (may be due to the font choice) and text is still white.

Comment: Probably should have read more closely - "able to update your grub without errors" which I am unable to. Hence why what you said has not worked.

Comment: speaking of which, I actually had just given up searching for answers and did exactly that. Came back to report my failure, and my discontinuation of grub customizer